# How to assign different function in multiple files?

Tags: c++-cli

This is how my task gonna be,

I have created a GUI which consist of two buttons as shown,

[image]

So, for the "browse captured file" button, I would have to open multiple files through OpenFIleDialog and read it. This is the code for open and read files.

```
Stream^ myStream;

OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
openFileDialog1->Title = "open captured file";
openFileDialog1->Filter = "CP files (*.cp)|*.cp|All files (*.*)|*.*|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialog1->Multiselect = true;

if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
     {

for each (String^ file in openFileDialog1->FileNames) 
{  

       array<String^>^ lines = System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(file);  

     for each (String^ line in lines) 
     {          
     }
}
```

After that, At the "Start Analysis" button, I would like to start implementation on each files. Files that I opened in OpenFileDialog for examples "1_1.cp", "2_1.cp" and "3_1.cp". I will start doing analysis on the files and each files has different data which going to perform different analysis.

Now my question is, how am I going to assign each opened files to do specific task or function. For example, 1_1.cp do task A, 2_1.cp do task B and so on? Anyone can help to suggest some ideas?

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but is this what you're looking for?

```
if(openFileDialog1->FileNames->Length > 0)
{
    TaskA(openFileDialog1->FileNames[0]);
}

if(openFileDialog1->FileNames->Length > 1)
{
    TaskB(openFileDialog1->FileNames[1]);
}

if(openFileDialog1->FileNames->Length > 2)
{
    TaskC(openFileDialog1->FileNames[2]);
}

// etc...
```